# Reference error is not thrown from MongoDB callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

### Introduction

All people know that if we call `undefined.test` we will receive the following error (same for both: NodeJS and Javascript):

```
$ node
> undefined.test
TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
    at repl:1:11
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

That's correct!

### How did I find the problem?

Passed week I wasted about 30 minutes in debugging the following problem: A script was stopping accidentally and no error was thrown.

I had the `urls` variable that was supposed to be an object:

```
var urls = settings.urls || {};
```

Then in next lines I needed to get `shop` key of `urls` that was a string:

```
var shop = urls.shop || "/";
```

I started adding `console.log` to find the values of variables:

```
console.log(urls);            // undefined
var shop = urls.shop || "/";
console.log("Passed");        // This isn't run.
```

The problem in my script was that I was redefining a **new** `urls` variable that was making the `urls` `undefined`, but the question is: why ***cannot read property "shop" of undefined*** didn't appear here? Because `urls` was really `undefined`.

We know that the following is happening in both: NodeJS and Javascript:

```
 var a = 10;
 foo(function () {
     console.log(a); // undefined
     var a = 10;
 });
 function foo(callback) { callback(); }
```

### The question

After debugging the problem I found that this problem comes from Mongo: inside of Mongo callbacks if we call `undefined.something` we **DON'T** get the error.

I've created a small script that demonstrates this:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");

// Mongo server
var server = mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017);
var db = new mongo.Db("test", server, { safe: true });

console.log("> START");

// Open database
console.log("Opening database.");
db.open(function(err, db) {
    if (err) { return console.log("Cannot open database."); }

    // get collection
    console.log("No error. Opening collection.");
    db.collection("col_one", function(err, collection) {
        if(err) { return console.log(err) }

        // do something with the collection
        console.log("No error. Finding all items from collection.");
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            if(err) { return console.log(err) }

            console.log("No error. Items: ", items);
            console.log("The following line is: undefined.shop." +
            "It will stop the process.");
            console.log(undefined.test); // THE ERROR DOES NOT APPEAR!
            console.log("> STOP"); // this message doesn't appear.
        });
    });
});
```

My questions are:

1. Why the error doesn't appear? Which is the reason? (It would be great to debug together the MongoDB source code to find it.)
2. Why the process is stopped when calling `undefined.something`?
3. How can be this solved?

I've created a [**Github repository**](https://github.com/DestroyingSoftware/MongoUndefined) where you can download my small application that demonstrates the issue.

---

Interesting:

If we add a `try {} catch (e) {}` statement we find the error and the process continue showing the `STOP` message.

```
try {
    console.log(undefined.test);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

LOGS:

```
> START
Opening database.
No error. Opening collection.
No error. Finding all items from collection.
No error. Items:  []
The following line is: undefined.shop. It will stop the process.
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined]
> STOP
```

Comment: you aren't using process.exit properly.  It takes a return code (integer), `0` for success and nonzero for failure.  This is directly from C and other languages that interact with the command line.  Behavior is described [here](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)

Comment: The `> STOP` message will not appear because the previous line gives error. Node will stop execution there and throw error. The error message may not show up if you are catching errors or listening to `uncaughtException`. Is there any error handling in your code ?

Comment: @user568109 Do you see the error? Does it appear? I don't see it! This is my question. Why doesn't it appear?

Comment: I grabbed mongodb from npm and concluded that: callbacks are often tested to see if they are of type function, collection.prototype.find() returns Cursor(), Cursor.prototype.toArray does not have an explicit try/catch block around the callback, but that doesn't mean there's not an outer try/catch somewhere.  I haven't tried to duplicate your initial problem, so this could be chasing phantoms for all I know.

Comment: Cursor.prototype.toArray implicates Cursor.prototype.each and Cursor.prototype.nextObject in constructing the array and then firing toArray's callback.  try/catch blocks look OK in that try/catch is used to detect errors in database code and callbacks are always called outside the try/catch, as expected.

Comment: Upgrade the driver and add an event handler for the "error" event on the db instance to catch any throw exceptions. Also I suggest writing unit/integration tests to catch these issue before actually putting your code into production. http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html

Comment: @christkv I use the latest version of Mongo.. It is updated automatically.

Comment: Very strange, I have the same issue inside an Express JS application. Wrapping a fictive console.log(blabla.blabla) in a try/catch block catches a ReferenceError, otherwise it's just silent (rest of the code  stops running). Any insight on what is the actual issue?

Comment: @Samson Let's ask Calin to detail [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18227729/1420197). Greetings from Romania! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on [github.com](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/b47792cc509b10cf969258491fea32d27c3c7b79) at `node-mongodb-native` driver issues, you will notice that issue is solved in `1.3.18` version. But, I tested it and it does not work as expected.

Comment: Can you please detail your answer? Why the error doesn't appear?  Which is the reason? Why the process is stopped when calling `undefined.something`? Can you reproduce the problem in a small Node application? Thanks!