# Mongodb errors specific code handling

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to output specific messages on specific responses.

Here is my code:

```
.post(function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);

  user.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      if(err.code == 11000)
        res.status(409).json(customHTTPcodeReponses.exists(req.body.email));
    };

    User.findById(user._id, function(err, createdUser) {
      res.status(201).json(customHTTPcodeReponses.created(createdUser));
    });
  });
});
```

Flow:

1. Posting data. I get 201.
2. Posting same data again. I get 409.
3. Posting same data again. I get "Could not get any response (POSTMAN)"

Console error:
    _http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

What could cause this?

Comment: "does not work" - elaborate

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18169275/4519059) can helps ;).

Comment: I have changed description. Can you please look at it again?

Comment: Did you try adding the `User.findById` code within an `else` statement? (`if(err){ .... } else { User.findById........ }`)

Comment: @shan1024 thank you, I did not realised `res` can be called twice. I avoided this by typing in return as result of `if(err)`. But I could use else statement as well.

Comment: You are welcome :) I will add that as an answer, then you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `User.findById` code within an else statement.

```
user.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      if(err.code == 11000)
        res.status(409).json(customHTTPcodeReponses.exists(req.body.email));
    }else{
        User.findById(user._id, function(err, createdUser) {
           res.status(201).json(customHTTPcodeReponses.created(createdUser));
        });
    }
  });
```

or add a return to the 1st response:

```
if(err.code == 11000)
    return res.status(409).json(customHTTPcodeReponses.exists(req.body.email));
```